# 16.04 - US International English changed behaviour after update

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

After latest (20-22 august) update the behaviour and layout of US International English changed.

After the update dead keys no longer works, for instance **Alt-Gr**+**`** and then **a** no longer gives à

In addition the key on the left of **1** is **´** instead of `` and the key on the left of **Enter** is ` instead of '

Setting **International AltGr dead keys** restores the quote keys but not the AltGr dead key.

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources: [('xkb', 'us+altgr-intl')]

gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current: uint32 0

Comment: With _English (US, international with dead keys)_ you are not supposed to use <AltGr> to access `dead_acute` and `dead_grave`. To see how it's supposed to work, you can run this command: `cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us | grep -m1 -A60 intl`

Comment: Let's assume that I am breaking some kind of rule (I had the same layout since... 11.x or so, naver changed and naver paid attention, just used it like in Windows).

What is the layout that gives me NO fancy quotes and AltGr as the last 5+ years?

Comment: I can't really tell which layout you used previously. ;) There is the basic _English (US)_ layout without dead keys. (But that's not what you asked about above.)